# What does "eau" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read it from a jewelry website relating to a bottle of perfume or cologne maybe?  Some sort of spray? I can't seem to find a definition on google.  I'm assuming French roots.

Comment: Try typing "eau" into Google and following a link to a dictionary. For example: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/eau

Comment: *eau* = water. However, the object in question could more likely be *eau de cologne* -- you can look up the phrase.

Comment: @SoylentGreen Hugo has access everywhere, lesser mortals have to google.

Comment: @SoylentGreen: Strange, I didn't check the actual M-W page because the Google summary showed the definition. Try this instead: http://www.onelook.com/?w=eau&ls=a&loc=2osdf

Comment: When looking up words on Google, it's a good idea to change the language preferences https://support.google.com/websearch/topic/3377479?hl=en&ref_topic=3036131  and/or go to Google.com or uk. I myself alternate between .uk to .it (Italy). To search results in English: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2807955?hl=en&ref_topic=3377479

Comment: In common US English usage the term will often be used (sometimes in a jocular sense) to mean "essence" or "odor".  For instance, it would not be unusual to hear someone describe some foul-smelling concoction as "eau de skunk".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**eau** means **water** in French. [Eau de cologne](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+eau+de+cologne&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is a fragrant liquid (toilet water, where toilet is French for the process of washing oneself, dressing, and attending to one's appearance, or denoting articles used in the process of washing and dressing oneself) with a strong, characteristic scent, originally made in Cologne, Germany.

Comment: Nobody has commented definitively on whether 'eau' is an accepted loanword in itself. Certainly open compounds such as _eau de vie_ "brandy" (1748), lit. "water of life" and _eau de toilette_ (1907) [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eau) have been accepted into the lexicon, but these are multi-word lexemes. For what it's worth, Sowpods lists **eau** (but then it seems to list most permutations of letters).

Comment: Susan, I don't understand what you mean by "*toilet water, where toilet is French...*". After reading that I thought there was a meaning to the word "toilet" I ignored and so I checked and I do know all the various meanings, so I'm puzzled and I hate not understanding, so if you can explain, I'd appreciate!

Comment: Sorry Susan I still don't understand why "toilet is French".  I do not know if it has to do with the construction of the sentence or the use of the word French here, what's French about it ? Is there something in Am English called "French toilet" that I can't see in the page you refer to (which adds nothing to the other dictionaries I had consulted).

Comment: @Susan: *toilet* is an English word; the French word is *toilette*.

Comment: Still not clear why you used the word French here, surely no one would understand the word toilet here as the room. The word toilet as "accessory to do the act of getting dressed" has nothing French about it. In English - as in French - the use of "toilet" as meaning "articles required or used in dressing" - in which we can include Cologne water is much older as its use to designate the room. (1662 according to the OED for English - 19th century for French). The use of the word as a euphemism to designate the "facility" only dates from the 19th century in English, 19th in French.

Comment: The OED gives nine different meanings to the word "toilet", all derivating from original word borrowed (16th century) from French *toilette* which is "a piece of stuff used as a wrapper for clothes" - and the French word meant exactly the same at the time (from latin *tela* - (cob)web). Present day uses of the English "toilet" and French "toilette" are exactly the same including the use of the room we call "toilettes" (we'd use it in the plural in that sense) when we want to use the special facilities there.

Comment: Until around 1900 or so, _toilette_ was a fancy term for washing your face and adjusting your makeup. Fashionable women would "make their toilette". Then it became (like _crapper, water closet, W.C._ and _commode_ before it) a euphemism for the place and the apparatus where one shits privately. This became the English word _toilet_.

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that, in the US, "eau" is more than occasionally used in a pseudo-hoity-toity humorous sense, with the assumed meaning being "essence" or "odor".  Someone might, eg, say "eau de skunk" or "eau de outhouse".  (The use of "de" to mean "of" is not required in this sense but is usual.)